# Issue on Using Rewrite Rule From A Folder to A PHP File with Same Name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having a root directly like below, as you can see I have a **Folder** and **File** with same named of **shop** can you please let me know how to write a  `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` to redirect any request like

> `http://clients/shop/` or `http://clients/shop`

to

> `http://clients/shop.php`

I already tried this

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.+) shop.php [L,R]
```

but this is adding wrong address of `http://clients/B:/WAMP/www/Clients/shop` to the URL

[image]

**==================== 

Update 

====================**

Okay I find this solution which is somehow working

```
DirectorySlash Off 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+shop [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.php [R=302,L]
```

This is however, fine only when the request is like `http://clients/shop` and it is showing the directory page when the request is like `http://clients/shop/`

Comment: What is the canonical URL? `/shop` or `/shop/`?

Comment: It might be `/shop` but I want to get the same result in both format, in case a user pass the url like `/shop/`

Answer (score 0):

This should get your job done

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /shop [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ shop.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks RaZoo but no still same thing!

Comment: I edited my answer plz try that it worked for me

Comment: I am afraid still not working! and now everything goes to 404